# Undefined Variable even if I passed it already

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I'm getting Undefined Variable error. Here is my controller:

Controller:

```
public function index()
{

    /**$englishgrades = StudentHistory::select('date', 'student_id', 'grade')
    ->where('subject', 'English')
    ->groupBy('student_id')
    ->orderBy('date','desc')
    ->first()
    ->get();        
    */  

    $englishgrades = StudentHistory::where('subject', 'English')
    ->get();        

    $englishgrades = [];

    return view('home', $englishgrades);
}
```

I'm calling it to my blade using

```
{{ $englishgrades }}
```

> Undefined variable: englishgrades (View: /home/vagrant/Code/projects/DYK/resources/views/home.blade.php)

Comment: you are overwriting with $englishgrades = [];

Comment: I deleted that, but it is still saying undefined variable

Comment: Remove your `$englishgrades = [];` and `return view('home', ['englishgrades' => $englishgrades]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use compact

```
$englishgrades = StudentHistory::where('subject', 'English')
->get();
$englishgrades = []; // remove this so it will not overwrite the above declaration ..
return view('home', compact('englishgrades'));
```

> it will return an empty array since you're overwriting the original value ..

Comment: This works, thanks! Can you give reference where can I read about 'compact'

Comment: compact is the same as doing as declaring an array with the key of the string and a value of the eval('$'. 'stringinput'); and put it an array but here: https://www.quora.com/What-does-compact-do-in-Laravel .. i hope it helps ..

Answer (score 1):

Remove your

```
$englishgrades = [];
```

and

```
return view('home', ['englishgrades' => $englishgrades]);
```

Comment: I am deleting my answer :)

Comment: @sumit I'm so sorry. Thank you bro.

Comment: How about the compact answer of @Demonyowh, which is proper?

Comment: @RodneyZanoria It's okay for both bro. Same purpose is return Object JSON to Blade view.

Answer (score 1):

```
return view('home', $englishgrades);
```

in above code second Argument is need to be a array key as a variable name and value as variable or value.

like

```
   return view('home',['englishgrades'=>$englishgrades]);
```

you can write by hand or use compact function to generate a array() of key value pair

```
  return view('home',compact('englishgrades'));
```

So Now you access a `$englishgrades` in a View

or you can use like

```
   $data = compact('englishgrades'); or 
   $data = ['englishgrades'=>$englishgrades];
   return view('home',$data);
```

here main thing is In View you use **key** as a **variable**
ex:

```
 $data = ['grades'=>$englishgrades];
   return view('home',$data);
```

So in View you have to use **$grades**